# Как в Navigation Drawer иконку пункта меню отобразить отличным от других цветом?

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

Думаю это сделать через ColorStateList, а может есть проще вариант? 
Еще есть вариант через создание LinearLayout внутри, но не хочется переделывать все меню ради одного элемента.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

            ...

       </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: Если еще не построили большой код, попробуйте [эту библиотеку](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer). Возможно, Вам она понравится. Я лично её использую. Очень гибкая настройка для каждого пункта.